# Need fix with CAR Rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am making a game where a car rotates around a cylinder. When i press left mouse click the car rotates to the left and when i press right mouse click the car rotates to the right. What i want is when i release the buttons the car should rotate to point forward (to go back to center) along the cylinder and not get stuck to the left or right.

Reminder: It's on cylinder and i do need a code, Thanks.

```
 rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
  rgb.MovePosition(rgb.position - transform.right * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);//move the car forward
  //rotating the car
          Vector3 yRot = Vector3.up * rotation * rotation_speed * Time.deltaTime;
          Quaternion deltaRot = Quaternion.Euler (yRot);
          Quaternion targetRot = rgb.rotation * deltaRot;
          rgb.MoveRotation (Quaternion.Slerp (rgb.rotation, targetRot, 50f * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

starting settings to explain my code

i have not the same axis than you are using..

at the middle of road, the value of X for the car is -5, -7.5 for left side and -2.5 for right side

**problem to resolve:**
When you press the left key, the car goes to left and when the key is released, the goal is to automatically go forward to x=-5 for the car..and dont forget to reset the rotation Y to 0

[image]

this code could be optimized, but its functional

Another approach will be to use Path with navmesh agent...but its another code too

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private enum Direction { Left = -1, Middle, Right };

    private Rigidbody rgb;

    public float moveSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float rotation_speed = 10f;

    public float rotation, currentRotation;
    public Vector3 currentPosition;

    private Direction currentDirection, lastDirection;
    private bool returnToMiddle;
    private float middlePositionX;

    public GameObject PieceOfRoad;
    private Queue<GameObject> PiecesOfRoad = new Queue<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        lastDirection = Direction.Middle;

        returnToMiddle = false;
        rgb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //initialize the initial middle position X of the car
        middlePositionX = rgb.position.x;

                // Load 4 pieces of road
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            PiecesOfRoad.Enqueue(Instantiate(PieceOfRoad, new Vector3(0f, 0f, i * 50f), Quaternion.identity));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentPosition = rgb.position;

        // Destroy the first piece of road of the Queue and create a new piece of road
        var z = PiecesOfRoad.Peek().transform.position.z;

        if (currentPosition.z > z + 50)
        {
            Destroy(PiecesOfRoad.Dequeue());
            PiecesOfRoad.Enqueue(Instantiate(PieceOfRoad, new Vector3(0f, 0f, z + 200f), Quaternion.identity));
        }
        //

        rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (rotation < 0)
            currentDirection = Direction.Left;
        else if (rotation > 0)
            currentDirection = Direction.Right;
        else
            currentDirection = Direction.Middle;


        // replace +transform.forward following your axis
        rgb.MovePosition(rgb.position + transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        // the return to middle is on but we press a new key
        if (returnToMiddle && currentDirection != Direction.Middle)
        {
            returnToMiddle = false;
        }

        // we have released key so return to middle is activated
        if (returnToMiddle && currentDirection == Direction.Middle)
        {
            // you could adjust the sensibility by increasing or decreasing the values (0.5f, 1.0f)
            if (lastDirection == Direction.Left && currentPosition.x > middlePositionX - 0.5f ||
                     lastDirection == Direction.Right && currentPosition.x < middlePositionX + 1.0f)
            {
                rgb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f),
                    5.0f * Time.deltaTime);
                currentRotation = rgb.transform.rotation.y;
                if (currentRotation < 0.01f) // if rotation is near 0, stop the autmatism
                    returnToMiddle = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CalculusNewRotation(-(int)lastDirection);
            }
            return;
        }


        if (currentDirection == Direction.Middle && !returnToMiddle)
        {
            if (lastDirection == Direction.Middle)
            {
                returnToMiddle = false;
                CalculusNewRotation(rotation);
            }
            else
            {
                returnToMiddle = true;
            }
            return;
        }

        if (currentDirection != Direction.Middle)
        {
            lastDirection = currentDirection;
            returnToMiddle = false;

            CalculusNewRotation(rotation);

        }

        void CalculusNewRotation(float rotation)
        {
            Vector3 yrot = Vector3.up * rotation * rotation_speed * Time.deltaTime;
            Quaternion deltaRot = Quaternion.Euler(yrot);
            Quaternion targetRot = rgb.rotation * deltaRot;
            rgb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Slerp(rgb.rotation, targetRot, 50f * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Good game!!

Comment: What i want is when i release the buttons the car should rotate to point forward along the cylinder. (Meaning, that you have to hold left/right buttons to steer, and when released the car should go back to middle, but still keep going forward, and i have infinite cylinders spawning forward, and the car goes forward infinite, it's a freeride gameplay, so if i add the car as child in a container GameObject (cylinder), it won't work on the others (cloned ones),  could you please write me a code for this so i can try it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok if i understood (english is not my first langage) you have a car and in front of the car, you have spawned cylinder the car must avoid... is it possible to have your unity package i put in my unity dev.. it will be faster and easier to test and adapt directly your code? i dont know to find solution without concrete sample...other people could but not me..

Comment: No, you should keep going on the cylinder, there are spawning cylinders in front of the car that the player can't see and you have a picture that is only a one cylinder, i just need the code when you release the buttons for left and right the car to go back to center, and car always goes forward btw it drives. (It's like you have a short road in front of you and car drives on the road, but to avoid performance loss you spawn more roads to look like one, and the ones you pass are destroyed, it's same just on cylinder).

Comment: ok sorry..i believe i begin to understand better.. its like you have a road with 3 lanes the left, middle and right and the cylinder is spwaned always in middle and the car could avoid it by left/right and you want when the button is released that the car go to middle automatically?

Comment: ok i have found a solution, i begin to modify my answer..just starting settings..before adding the new code

Comment: if my answer could help you dont forget to upvote and/or validate the answer please